# Why does telnet think I am requesting a page with an extra forward slash inserted at front?

Tags: http, proxy, get, telnet

I am trying to make a simple forwarding proxy.
It works for most websites but does not work for others.
One website that fails is http://www.cs.washington.edu/
When I open this website with firefox which uses my proxy, I get a 404 Not Found response. Displayed on the page is the following message "The requested page "/http://www.cs.washington.edu/" could not be found." Why is there an extra forward slash inserted at the start?

Then I try "telnet www.cs.washington.edu 80" with 
GET http://www.cs.washington.edu/ HTTP/1.0
and I get the same 404 Not Found response with the same headers and body (including the extra forward slash inserted).

Why is there an extra forward slash being inserted at the start of the url?
I am almost certain that I am requesting the page WITHOUT the forward slash inserted to the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTTP/1.0, you can't use absolute URLs in the request line (just insert the full path).

Comment: To be precise you MAY be able to use absolute URL in an HTTP/1.0 request, but the server may prefer a regular 'relative url' + host header. It depends on the server policy, and especially on security tools which may not like the fact you are using a very very very old version of the protocol (absolute uri in location).